# C++ style: Helper functions for a class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a redis clone. I have a class `Query` which processes Redis queries. Each query's starting word is a command in redis, eg: `GET foo` or `SET foo 123`. When parsing each query I want to call a function which will parse the query according to the starting word.

I have created an `std::map<std::string, std::string(*)(std::string)>` from string to pointer to functions.

```
//So when I get a query like:
query = "GET foo";

//I extract get in a string query_type. 
//And use this to do the required work on the query:
query_handler[query_type](query);

//This should call the function associated with "GET"
```

Now the question I have is where should these functions go? Within the class definition? Or a separate namespace? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Instead of using raw functions you may want to define a simple command handler class and use that instead. Each class will be required to implement a number of methods if you make your base class pure virtual.

Comment: voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's exactly what I need. If we(beginners) cant ask such questions here, could you suggest a place where we should?

Comment: I would suggest an actual forum like codeguru

Comment: @NathanOliver I will take care next time. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking at the types of questions that are on topic at http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: My question would be: why does query need to be a class to begin with? Can't query just be a function? In that case I would make the std::map (or perhaps std::unordered_map) a static local of the function.